# decodeing of image string to bitmap from php server

Tags: android

I have encoded image to image string and posted to php server, it is successful , when I am getting back image string to display posted image like below;

here i am getting bitmap from json data

```
try{
Bitmap imageBitmap = decodeBase64(data.getString("Image").toString);
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap );
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

function for getting bitmap

```
public Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
     try {
           byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
           return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
         } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
         }
}
```

But image not displaying and in log cat show

03-31 13:40:34.117: D/skia(2524): --- decoder->decode returned false

please suggest me where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
try {
Bitmap bitmap = null;
if(input!= null){
byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString,0,decodedString.length);
}
return bitmap;
}catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
}
}

try this just a minor change in your code.
```